# SpringMVC + Groovy in Openshift

Tags: groovy, jenkins, openshift

I have used this [Gradle Openshift quickstart](https://github.com/shekhargulati/gradle-openshift-quickstart) to use gradle with openshift, everything worked even with Jenkins!

But, I wanna use `Groovy`, so I added the follow code in my `build.gradle` to compile groovy scripts to `.class`

See

```
  sourceSets{
main{
    java{
        srcDir "src/main/java"
    }
    resources{
        srcDir "src/main/java"
    }

    groovy{
        srcDir "src/main/java"

    }
}
test.java.srcDir "src/test/java"

}
```

It works locally, I'm using Tomcat7, but when I deploy the jenkins build fails with the message

```
:compileJava
:compileGroovy FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
 > java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --              debug option to get more log output.
```

So, the problem is about `Permission denied` when gradle try to execute `compileGroovy` task, I guess is something in the OpenShift OS but I don't know what's wrong, I have inserted the follow code in the files `.openshift/build` and `.openshift/pre-build`, see below

pre_build file

```
if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/gradle-1.6 ]
 then
   cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
   mkdir gradle
   wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip
   unzip gradle-1.6-bin.zip
   rm -f gradle-1.6-bin.zip
 fi

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/groovy ]
  then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
    mkdir groovy
    wget http://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.4.1.zip
    unzip groovy-binary-2.4.1.zip
    rm -f groovy-binary-2.4.1.zip
fi
```

build file

```
   cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
   echo SETTING GRADLE HOME
   export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/gradle
   export GRADLE_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/gradle-1.6
   export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
   gradle build

   export GROOVY_USER_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/groovy
   export GROOVY_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/groovy
   export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Well, I can't compile groovy files inside openshift even I have installed the groovy, how to make groovy works on Openshift?

Comment: is there a way get the stracktrace (e.g. with the mentioned option).  java's exception messages are rather useless.  there might be a chance to see the problem in the trillion lines of calls of the trace.

Comment: I'm not saying this is your problem, but in the build file above you start your grade build before setting your groovy environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment MartinB, but I've noticied that and I changed it, the problem is about permission, that's it, in OpenShift we don't have full control of the machine, our user does not has rights to set example chmod for our files, I'd like to use OpenShift but it's not easy, now I'm using Digital Ocean and I configured my own machine. It's working there

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`usually means that you are trying to setup a server socket or comparable on a port you don't have permission for. This could be the firewall blocking, or on Linux systems a too low port number reserved for privileged users like root. I think OpenShift uses port in the 15000+ range, so the firewall is the most likely problem.

Comment: The question is, how can I change the port? and why the exception occur exactly in :compileGroovy task?. To sumarize, I need to use groovy and the gradle can't compile it :(

Comment: Try what gradle suggest and run the build with `--stacktrace` before we do not get any information from that it is difficult to see the real nature of the issue

Comment: I've fixed the issue, well, I've used my own machine on DigitalOcean and I've faced with the same issue, I gave sudo rights to "jenkins" user and it worked, the problem is that I cannot set the same rights in OpenShift, I've connected in OpenShift with ssh and tried to set the same rights and I dont have permission, I think the solution is change the host! :( unfortunately